# C#, SQL Server: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I'm coding database access methods with C#, Entity Framework and SQL Server.

After my database update, I started to get odd "*The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint*" error messages. I notice the error with only one database table A when executing my unit tests in Visual Studio.

The scenario for my unit test is as follows:

1. The database table A has multiple many-to-one relations to other tables
2. The database table A has **FK**s, which point to the **PK** of other tables
3. All the data rows are properly inserted and commited to other tables (**PK** *Guids* are unique)
4. When debugging with C#, all the database table A **FK**s *Guid* values are correctly been set for the C# context.TableA.Add(item) statement
5. When debugging with the SQL Server Profiler, the created SQL **INSERT** statement has the correct *Guid* values for each **FK** in the statement

As the result, the **INSERT** statement gives *the FOREIGN KEY constraint* error message. The **INSERT** fails *with every single FK* in it, and the **INSERT** is successful only after I delete all the **FK**s from the Table A.

Therefore, I think I might have something wrong with my SQL server, or the with the table A.

Here's some statistics of the Table A

1. It has about 80 columns
2. Each row is approximately 10 kB large
3. The table is empty when performing the **INSERT**

I would be most happy to receive any hints for progressing with this item!

Comment: can you show us the table design for table A and for one the the tables it references with a FK ?

Comment: are the FK's in all other values set to the correct A they are attached to (at runtime)?

Comment: 80 columns on table A? Wow that's a lot of columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I think I found a solution for my problem.

I am using DeZing for Databases tool for my database design, and creation of database creation scripts.

I have drawn a relationship from table A to the other table. The relationship had two keys connected as follows

**Table A <--------------------------------> CustomerAddress**

*PK Guid*

*FK CustomerAddressGuid <-------> PK Guid*

*FK CustomerGuid <------------------> FK CustomerGuid*

Now the DeZing for Databases tool ordered

*FK CustomerGuid <------------------> FK CustomerGuid* (FK relations first) and

*FK CustomerAddressGuid <-------> PK Guid* (PK relations as next)

So, even the values were correct, the INSERT failed, because the FK - FK relation was prior to PK - FK.

Unfortunately the DeZing tool did not resolve this scenario automatically, and the relationship order was not easily visible in the tool.

The solution was to re-arrange the linked attributes order in the tool (*PK attributes first*), and re-create the database creation script.